# On the main site, upvotes aren't giving a reputation change

Tags: support, reputation

I apologize for the small picture. There are some of my answers that have been up/down-voted (more up than down), but there is no "+#" next to my two most recent posts. One has 4 upvotes, the other has 2. Why is this not updating?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congratulations! You hit the [reputation cap](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#link-reputation-gain) today:

> A maximum of 40 votes can be cast per user per day, however, to reach the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions. **You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day (although accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit).** Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate reputation.

You may end up with less rep, but you did earn a nice [mortarboard badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/25/mortarboard?userid=10893).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that existed until just now. I should have done better on due diligence, but thank you for your help!